# Why geometryInstances not showing on Cesium 3D model?

Tags: cesium, 3d-model

I have the following code, but geometryInstances is not showing up on my 3D model.

```
         propertyPlacemark.push(viewer.entities.add({
      geometryInstances : new Cesium.GeometryInstance({
              geometry : Cesium.BoxGeometry.fromDimensions({

                dimensions : new Cesium.Cartesian3(8.0, 5.0, 8.0)
              }),
              modelMatrix : Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByTranslation(Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(
    Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(parseFloat(block[2]),parseFloat(block[1]))), new Cesium.Cartesian3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), new Cesium.Matrix4()),
              attributes : {
                color : Cesium.ColorGeometryInstanceAttribute.fromColor(new Cesium.Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5)),

              },

            })
    }));

*parseFloat(block[2])= longitude
parseFloat(block[1])= latitude
```

Expected outcome：
[image]